# Implement event delegation from document body by default

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, magnific-popup

My issue start from a problem in IE8 when loading dynamic html pages that contain script tags via ajax (using magnificPopup.js).Therefore I had to remove all the js code from these dynamically called pages and put them in a seperate .js file but then it requires using .on for every single jQuery selector as all the elements were not on the page when the new .js page was loaded with the parent page.

Q: is there a way to make every single jQuery selector

```
$('#myId') or $('.myClass')
```

to work as follows

```
$('body').on('click','#myId',function(){
   /*my code ...*/
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the right solution would be to call your functions in the ajax callback block.

You'd put your behaviors in a named function, which can be loaded about anywhere:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('.myClass').click(function() { ... });
}
```

And then call that after the new file is loaded via ajax:

```
$.ajax({...})  
.success(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I used your idea. It just took me a while to  figure out how to use it with  the updateStatus method of magnificPopup (its the one that mimics the ajax success method)